# What does the "goatman drum" do?

Tags: diablo-iii

While wondering the Southern and Northern Highlands in act 1, I'm occasionally encountering a "goatman drum" item:

[image: goatman drum screenshot]

I've also seen Goatmen actually walk up to it and start drumming, though I couldn't quite understand what the effect, if any, was. What does it do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It buffs the Goatmen around the drum making them stronger and bigger. Also slower as well.