# What does beating on a goatmen drum do?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the “goatman drum” do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67154/what-does-the-goatman-drum-do)

In the highlands there are goatmen drums scuttered around, when I get near them and a group of goatmen, one of them will start beating on them (as in the picture). What does that do?
[image: Screenshot of an extra large goatman beating a drum.]

Comment: From what I have been able to tell it buffs nearby goatmen, as they all grow to the same size as the one beating the drum (and emit a red aura).  I won't post as an answer as I do not have any official facts or sources.

Comment: This was already answered here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67154/what-does-the-goatman-drum-do

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have seen the goatmen grow larger when beating on the drum.  Not just the drummer, but all Kazra within a certain distance grow larger.  Shortly after the drumming stops (either they hit whatever limit they're looking for, or you destroy the drum), the goatmen will shrink back down to normal size.

The only ability I know of that makes monsters grow is Avenger, where champions grow larger and hit harder when you kill their friends.  I suspect the goatmen's larger size is to convey the same information; they hit harder.